# Area of metric ball on n-sphere

Tags: area, spheres

Suppose $S_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} : ||x||_2 = 1\}$ is the $n$-sphere. Let $d : S_n^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be the angle metric on $S_n$, i.e. $d(x, y) = \arccos(x \cdot y)$, where $\cdot$ is the dot product.

What is the area $A(D_n(\theta))$ of the disk $D_n(\theta) = \{x \in S_n : d(x, p) \leq \theta\}$, where $p \in S_n$?

I'm not sure of the terminology here, and whether I'm missing some information. I suspect this has to do with Riemannian manifolds, but I know little about them. Intuitively, I want to define probability densities on $S_n$, those densities being relative to area. At least for $n \leq 3$ the idea seems clear. Clearly $A(D_1(\theta)) = 2$, and $A(D_2(\theta)) = 2 \theta$. Looking at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

we have $A(D_3(\theta)) = 2\pi (1 - \cos(\theta))$.

Edit: The same page in fact gives the general formula. It just has to be transformed to use angle rather than height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia's spherical cap article provides the area of (a boundary of) a spherical cap with height $h(\theta)$ and sphere-radius $r$ as

$$A(D_n(\theta)) = (1/2) A_n r^{n - 1} I(\alpha(\theta), (n - 1) / 2, 1 / 2),$$

where

$$A_n = \frac{2 \pi^{n / 2}}{\Gamma(n / 2)},$$
$$\alpha(\theta) = (2rh(\theta) - h(\theta)^2) / r^2,$$
$$h(\theta) = r - r \cos(\theta),$$
$$I(x, a, b) = \frac{B(x, a, b)}{B(a, b)}.$$

Here $A_n$ is the area of the boundary of the unit $n$-ball, $I$ is the regularized incomplete beta function, and $B$ is the (incomplete) beta function. Expanding the definitions,

$$\alpha(\theta) = 2(1 - \cos(\theta)) - (1 - \cos(\theta))^2.$$

This can further be simplified to

$$\alpha(\theta) = \sin(\theta)^2.$$

The formula for $A(D_n(\theta))$ above is valid only when $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi / 2$, corresponding to $0 \leq h(\theta) \leq r$. When $\pi / 2 \leq \theta$, the formula is given by $A_n r^{n - 1} - A(\pi - \theta)$.